# nuxt with locomotive-scroll and gsap issue on route change

Tags: nuxt.js, gsap, smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll, scrolltrigger

I have been straggling to achieve a smooth scrolling effect on my Nuxtjs project using the locomotive scroll and gsap scrollTrigger and Scrollproxy. But having some wired issues on my halfway which I can't go back to.  I am using Typescript and Class Component in my Nuxt project.

here is my code [repo](https://github.com/anku598/locomotive-scroll-issue-demo-for-stackoveflow)  and [demo link](https://locomotive-site-with-nuxt.netlify.app/)

**issues are**

1. Changing route the scroll effect is broken and page height is going so high. then have to hard reload that specific page only works properly. need a solution for route change which i don't have any clue about in this setup.

this is the code

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]')

const bodyScrollBar = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: scrollContainer,
    smooth: true,
    initPosition: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    lerp: 0.12,
    getSpeed: true,
    getDirection: true,
    offset:["15%",0],
    tablet: {
        smooth: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        gestureDirection: 'vertical',
        breakpoint: 1024
    },
    smartphone: {
        smooth: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        gestureDirection: 'vertical'
    }
})

bodyScrollBar.on('scroll', ScrollTrigger.update)

  ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy('.scroller-wrapper', {
                scrollTop(value) {
                    if(arguments.length) {
                        
                        return arguments.length ?
                        bodyScrollBar.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)  :
                        bodyScrollBar.scroll.instance.scroll.y
                        // return bodyScrollBar.scrollTop = value
                    }
                },
                getBoundingClientRect() {
                    return {
                        left: 0, top: 0,
                        width: window.innerWidth,
                        height: window.innerHeight
                    }
                },
               
                pinType:  scrollContainer.style.transform ? "transform" : "fixed"
            })

ScrollTrigger.addEventListener('refresh', () => bodyScrollBar.update())
ScrollTrigger.addEventListener('resize', () => bodyScrollBar.update())


ScrollTrigger.refresh(true)
```

2. locomotive has instances for parallax and other effects like `data-scroll` and `data-scroll-speed='1'` . it's working correctly when refreshing the page but when I change route it's not working. you can see it on my [demo-project-link](https://locomotive-site-with-nuxt.netlify.app/).
3. Want to scroll a specific section on the page which has `overflow-scroll` and a fixed `height`. But when trying to scroll the whole page is going to scroll which is not expected. to see go to the `**scrollable-div**`  menu from the navigation.

[image]
This section I want to scroll differently and need to stop the whole page scrolling when I scroll this section.

Need your support and solution as i am stuck with these wired issues. any solution will be appriciate.

Comment: I've answered a few things about locomotive-scroll, not sure if this can help anyhow.

Comment: @kissu can you share those answered link please? Thank you

Comment: Damn, sorry forgot to paste the links! https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+locomotive-scroll

Comment: @kissu i tried it but it didn't work and  won't fullfil my purpose. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When I use `locomotive-scroll` and Nuxt.js, I always set the `scroll-container` and run a new instance of `locomotive-scroll` inside every page, also I destroy that instance using the `beforeDestroy()` hook.

This way, the instance knows the content it has inside and setup every animation and position, the other way if you change the route, the instance is the same but the DOM is different.

A full example of a page:

```js
<template lang="pug">
div(ref="scroll")
  h1 Your HTML here
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      scroll: undefined
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy () {
    if (typeof this.scroll !== 'undefined') {
      this.scroll.destroy()
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.enableLocomotiveScroll()
    })
  },

  methods: {
    enableLocomotiveScroll () {
      if (process.client && typeof this.scroll === 'undefined') {
        this.scroll = new this.LocomotiveScroll({
          el: this.$refs.scroll,
          smooth: true
        })

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.scroll.update()
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Of course you can [move this functionality to a mixin](https://medium.com/@seyijosh44/how-to-use-mixins-in-nuxt-js-826724fa251) and just load it in every page to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: Hey, @sergio I appreciate your solution. But this doesn't fulfill the purpose that I am looking for.  especially problem number 3.  When I have a scrollable section on a particular page in the body I have to stop the whole body scrolling when I scroll that section. This is also an important issue to which I am looking for a solution. it would be great if you try for that solution. also in your solution isn't work when I resize the window. it's break and adds too much space in the bellow. 
Thanks